# Volume of convex body in terms of its radial function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, volume, convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a convex body (i.e a non-empty, convex, compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) such that has the origin as an interior point  and $\rho(K,u)=\max\{\lambda \geq 0: \lambda u \in K\}$ be its radial function, I want to prove that
$$\operatorname{vol}(K)=\dfrac{1}{n} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\rho(u,K)^n \mathrm{d}u$$

I've thought about some change of variables but I don't see how to do it working with a function that is defined as a maximum. If someone could give a detailed proof I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Yes, this is just change of variables formula. You start with $vol(K) = \int1dx$ and then pass to spherical coordinates. That is, if $x = (x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ each  $x_k=r*(expression which does not depend on r)$ and the scope of r is from 0 to $ \rho(K,u)=\max\{\lambda \geq 0: \lambda u \in K\}$

Comment: @Salcio Could you explain it on detail, please? Because I get the idea, but I don't really see it properly and I don't exactly know how to aply a spherical change of coordinates in dimension greater than $3$

Comment: I guess, this is a standard topic in Calculus 2+ so I refer to sources. For example, read a Wiki article on n-dimensional sphere at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere